# Find max and min of a subset of an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, max, min

I wanted to find the maximum and minimum from part of array. I know I can get the required part of the array into another array by copying it but just want to know if it is possible without copying the array as I have to go through a loop for different sub array's

For example:

```
arr1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

Now I want to find the min/max of the subarray from 1 to 4 (if possible without copying subarray)

Comment: Do you know how to get the max/min yourself for the whole array? If not, start by doing that. Then you just need to loop from 1 to 4 and use the same logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Skip` and `Take` methods to select the subset of the array before calling the `Max` or `Min` methods.

For example, to get the maximum number from the first four elements of the array

```
Dim arr1() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
Dim arrMax As Integer = arr1.Take(4).Max
```

Or if you want to skip the first element and get the maximum number of the next four elements of the array

```
Dim arr1() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
Dim arrMax As Integer = arr1.Skip(1).Take(4).Max
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I am having 2 dimensional array for the above operation, How can pass array to arr1.Take(4).Max line? i want to use 1st column of 2 dimensional array.

Comment: Processing one row of a 2-D array is not so easy. If arr1 declared as `Dim arr1(,) As Integer = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}` and you consider the first dimension to be the "row" and the second to be the "column", you could use `Dim arrMax As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Max(Function(c) arr1(0, c))` to get the first 4 columns of the first row.